# Insert content into iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to insert some content into a 'blank' iFrame, however nothing is being inserted.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
$("#iframe").ready(function() {
    var $doc = $("#iframe").contentWindow.document;
    var $body = $("<body>").text("Test");
    $body.insertAfter($doc);
});
```

I am calling the `ready` function so I don't understand why it is not inserting.

Comment: You have the ID wrong at line 2 of your JavaScript, for a start

Comment: @Indy Still not working though

Comment: The id of the iframe shouldn't start with a #. `<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>`

Comment: Your HTML is also incorrect, I assume you mean ``id="iframe"``

Comment: @freefaller Still doesn't work though ^^

Comment: Are you calling all the code within a `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You really don't need jQuery for that:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('Test');
doc.close();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/)

If you absolutely have to use jQuery, you should use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
var $iframe = $('#iframe');
$iframe.ready(function() {
    $iframe.contents().find("body").append('Test');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TH48e/1/)

Please don't forget that if you're using jQuery, you'll need to hook into the DOMReady function as follows:

```
$(function() {  
    var $iframe = $('#iframe');
    $iframe.ready(function() {
        $iframe.contents().find("body").append('Test');
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree that jQuery is a bit overkill for some simple DOM manipulation but I've already got it for other parts of the page anyway, but thanks for the detailed response

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please bear in mind though that using jQuery is not always best option. In this example, it will be slower, of course.

Comment: Anyone faced any cross-domain security validations thrown by IE ? I am seeing those with this example. Any idea on how to work arounds ?

Comment: Changed to `var ifr = d.getElementById('iframe'), doc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;`. Got it from http://thinkofdev.com/javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe

Comment: This is not a bad solution because many browsers give you a warning when you use doc.write(); it is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you want:

```
$("#iframe").ready(function() {
    var body = $("#iframe").contents().find("body");
    body.append('Test');
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbfz3/) for working demo.

**Edit:** You can of course do it one line style:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").append('Test');
```

Comment: Just because he's named variables with `$` doesn't mean it's a weird combination of PHP and JS. I actually sometimes name variables that hold jQuery objects as `$testDiv`, for example. It helps me track jQuery objects inside my code... The prepended `$` on variable names has nothing to do with JS syntax...

Comment: Ok sorry, offensive tone removed.

Comment: @PavelŠtěrba None taken :)

Comment: If you're using the jquery function `find` does that mean the iframe already has a body tag in it - or am I missing somehting?

Comment: @user2521439 yes. iframes are created with a blank document inside. The browser will automatically add `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` to your iframe's contentDocument.

Answer (score 4):

Wait, are you really needing to render it using javascript?

**Be aware that in HTML5 there is `srcdoc`, which can do that for you!** (The drawback is that IE/EDGE does not support it yet https://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc)

See here [`srcdoc`]: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp

Another thing to note is that if you want **to avoid the interference of the js** code inside and outside  you should **consider using the `sandbox`** mode.

See here [`sandbox`]: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can enter (for example) text from div into iFrame:

```
var $iframe = $('#iframe');
$iframe.ready(function() {
    $iframe.contents().find("body").append($('#mytext'));
});
```

and divs:

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
<div id="mytext">Hello!</div>
```

and JSFiddle demo: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/marinavillada/qwa2xyqg/)

Comment: It would be better to have text in English (even though in this case understanding it is not very important). Also, as a general tip, a few words to explain how your solution works would be welcome. It would save people from analysing the code to understand whether your solution is what they are looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the `CSS` thats on your webpage in your `IFrame`, try this:

```
var headClone, iFrameHead;

// Create a clone of the web-page head
headClone = $('head').clone();

// Find the head of the the iFrame we are looking for
iFrameHead = $('#iframe').contents().find('head');

// Replace 'iFrameHead with your Web page 'head'
iFrameHead.replaceWith(headClone);

// You should now have all the Web page CSS in the Iframe
```

Good Luck.