# HTML Injection like Buffer App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-injection, html-injections

Buffer App inserts an additional button on twitter pages whenever you view in browser after installing their plug-in. Buffer button is just an additional share button that appears inline html placing an additional button next to twitter actions (retweet, quote, etc.)

You can also do this with Firebug or browser developer mode where you modify the source.

I would like to do something similar using a web page or a frame and JavaScript (frame is not a must).

I have a scenario where I do an in-frame redirect to an external page over which I have no control over. I can only modify my redirect page. I need to hide a few DIVs from that external page which shouldn't be too difficult using JQuery.

However I'm still considering how to access the source of another document (in another frame or div) using JQuery and modify it.

Any advice on how to achieve this? Or if there's an alternative solution, that would be welcomed too.

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe)

Comment: thanks giving it a try.

Comment: I'm getting cross domain validation on the browser level using IE - as its trying to modify DOM from another domain.