# Placeholder content for iframe

Tags: javascript, php

I am wanting to automatically display content from my databse within an iframe as it acts as the body content which was submitted when creating the doc.

I am trying to insert with a mix of JS Php like so:

```
<iframe name="editor" id="editor" class="doc_body" ></iframe></div>

<script> 
var iframe = document.getElementById('editor'), 
iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; 
iframedoc.body.innerHTML ="<?php echo ($row[2]); ?>"; 
</script>
```

I know that I am indexing correctly because if I echo this out of the JS it will output the correct row.

Unless the syntax is wrong above?

**UPDATED**

so after some messing around it would appear that there is a conflict between this:

```
    <?php    


    $q = "SELECT * FROM cats";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.


    // FETCH AND PRINT ALL THE RECORDS
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo '<ul><li><label><input type="checkbox" <?php if ($checked == 1) echo "checked"; name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li></ul>';
    }

    ?>
```

And the above, If I remove this above the content shows but if I include it - it takes it away?

Comment: Why bother with an iframe

Comment: Because it is part of my WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Your edit shows invalid php. Is error check ing on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is solved right here ;)

[Insert content into iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe)

```
<iframe name="editor" id="editor" class="doc_body" ></iframe></div>

<script> 
  var doc = document.getElementById('editor').contentWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(<?php echo ($row[2]); ?>);
  doc.close();
</script>
```

hope it helps, working fiddle can be found in the link i posted above

Comment: Hmm it made it all go a bit funny - its a conflict between some Php I believe... see my update

Comment: Well no my php is not invalid - I have actually solved the issue by creating it as a function instead of having the php directly in the div. no errors now.

Comment: $html = '<ul><li><label><input type="checkbox";

if ($checked == 1) $html .= " checked name='cat_id' value='". $row['cat_id'] ."'>". $row["cat_name"]. '</label></li></ul>';

echo $html;