# added js code doesn't work in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an Iframe containing a div tag with "firstHeadSection" id.

after iframe is loaded, I append this code to iframe:

```
    <script>
    $(window).on("resize", function(){
    alert($("#firstHeadSection").height())
    })
    </script>
```

The Js code will be inserted but after I resize window, it alerts null.

JQuery is included in the iframe.

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert content into iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe)

Comment: We would probably need to see some more JS/HTML with regards to how you insert the iframe, how you append the script etc...

Comment: Most likely there's no element with id `firstHeadSection` at the time you're trying to refer it. Make sure you don't have typos in the `id`s, and validate the markup in the iframe..

Answer (score 0):

You have to access to the main page, so you have to prepend "parent". Try something like this: (not tested)

```
parent.$.fn.resize(function() {
    alert($("#firstHeadSection").height());
});
```

Comment: An iframe gets resized as well - it depends, yes, but it does receive this event so this is not really the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks for the object with id "#firstHeadSection" in $(window), but with iframe you have to query its DOM like:

```
<script>
  $(window).on("resize", function(){
    alert($("#iFrameID").contents().find("#firstHeadSection").height())
  });
</script>
```

I haven't test it... Please post more of your code to be able to do it reliably...

Comment: If the code is _inside_ the iframe, then this wouldn't work. CORS also applies in some cases. I think we need more code to be able to help here.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I think his problem is in the scope where he is looking for the DOM object, I believe jQuery is looking for it outside the iframe... he should refer to the iframe internal DOM as an object and query it, well at least give it a try...

Comment: Might be, but he also mentions 'after iframe is loaded, I append this code to iframe', which doesn't rule this out, but we need more information...

Comment: yes, is he appending the code to the iframe DOM or to the iframe element...

Comment: In that case the code would, when done correctly, run _inside_ the iframe, right (again, disregarding possible CORS errors)? I'm unsure and I don't want to fix on an idea until the OP gives us a little more to go on than guesses.