# Featherlight, JavaScript source for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, iframe, featherlight.js

I'm evaluating Featherlight lightbox and I'm not able to implement code that satisfies my use case. I need a lightbox that will be used as a report viewer which displays dynamically created content assigned to a JavaScript variable. The value of the string is a valid HMTL5 page.

I've looked at the iframe example, but it depends upon a static iframe being in the DOM. That's not what I need.

I've reviewed this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/issues/52) and this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dNvz/) and I'm not able to successfully modify the fiddle to display a string.

This is an example of the string I would like to display:

```
var s = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Title of the document</title></head><body><p>Content of the document......</p></body></html>';
```

Is this possible and if so how?

I expect that `$.featherlight()` will be called manually in response to a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to modify the Featherlight source code in 2 places as indicated in this block of code (currently around line 383).

```
        iframe: {
            process: function(url) {
                var deferred = new $.Deferred();
                var $content = $('<iframe/>')
                    .hide()
                    .attr('src', url)
                    .attr('id', this.namespace + '-id') // [KT] 10/31/2016
                    .css(structure(this, 'iframe'))
                    .on('load', function() {if ($content.show()) {deferred.resolve($content.show()) } else {deferred.resolve($content)} ; })  // [KT] 10/31/2016

                    // We can't move an <iframe> and avoid reloading it,
                    // so let's put it in place ourselves right now:
                    .appendTo(this.$instance.find('.' + this.namespace + '-content'));
                return deferred.promise();
            }
        },
```

The `id` attribute is added to the `iframe` so content can be added by JavaScript, like this:

```
    var s = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Title of the document</title></head><body><p>Content of the document......</p></body></html>';
    var oIframe = document.getElementById('featherlight-id');  // Featherlight's iframe
    var iframeDoc = (oIframe.contentDocument || oIframe.contentWindow.document);
    iframeDoc.open();
    iframeDoc.write(s);
    iframeDoc.close();
```

This then works:

```
   $.featherlight({iframe: 'about:blank', iframeWidth: '96%' });
```

The 2nd modification is required so that the url `'about:blank'` doesn't raise an error.

I also modified the css so as to get the scroll bars to work as needed.

**Edit:** the issue with Featherlight not opening an `iframe` when the url is `abount:blank` has been fixed as of version 1.5.1.

**Edit 2:** Using v1.5.1, this works without having to make a modification to Featherlight to add an `id` to to the `iframe`:

```
    var s = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Title of the document</title></head><body><p>Content of the document......</p></body></html>';
    $.featherlight({iframe: 'about:blank'});
    var $iframe = $('.featherlight iframe');
    $iframe.ready(function () {
        $iframe.contents().find("body").append(s);
    });
```

The accepted [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe) was used for this solution.

Comment: The custom code is no longer necessary: https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/issues/256#issuecomment-257747564