# Tracking an event on a mail formular within an iframe

Tags: email, iframe, google-tag-manager, mail-form, samesite

I am having some trouble with setting up tracking in GTM. The tag i have create doesn't fire, when someone sends us an mail.

I want to track, how many mails are sent from a contact form within a iframe on my site.
The mail-form is provide by the our CMS system, and i have access to the source of that iframe.

My setup in GTM looks like this:

```
Trigger configuration
Triggertype: Formular sent
Wait for tags 2000 milliseconds
Check to validate

Page path: contains contact-us

Click id: listform3883_sendbutton

Tag configuration
Tag type: Google Analytics - Universal Analytics
Tracking tyoe: event
Categories: Sent mail 
Label: {{ Form ID }}
{{Google Analytics - UA }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The important aspect here is whether or not the iframe is on the same domain**:

- **If it's not**: you cannot interact with it from the parent page [due to security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame), so you will need GTM to be installed on the iframe page itself (ie the iframed page is served with GTM inside it).
- **if it is**: then you can just [inject GTM into the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe) (like you would inject any HTML into an iframe) if it's not already in the iframe.

**Once GTM is running on the iframe**, then it's a simple form tracking task that has nothing to do with the issue of iframes.

Comment: Okay. The iframe is on the same domain. So if  i have understood this correctly. All i have to do is insert the gtm script on the content in the iframe?